# How to enable CURL on Mac when running composer?

Tags: php, macos, curl

I'm trying to install Braintree package via composer and get the following error:

```
- braintree/braintree_php 3.39.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system
```

However, if I type `curl -V` on the same terminal, it is actually installed:

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) libcurl/7.54.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k
zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http
https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp
smtps telnet tftp  Features: IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO
NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

I'm on latest Mac OS, so I cannot uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini as that won't work.

Comment: Not being able to uncomment that extension is the problem. You need to install it on your server first though. It's something like `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` depends on your php version. `php5-curl`, `php6-curl`, or `php7-curl`

Comment: I mean I shouldn't uncomment since it's a DLL anyway. And it is actually installed as you can see, version 7.54.0

Comment: Yes I see curl is installed. There is `curl` and there is **php curl extension** and without both you can't use curl in php. Braintree and most php api sdks use curl to send requests to their endpoints.